# Need a quick regex for a numeric range between 2000 to 9999

Tags: java, regex, range, numeric

I am rather bad at regex's and am unsure of how to do this numeric range.

EDIT: Sorry about being vague, i need to check if the string inputted is between the numeric range 2000 to 9999, it will not have any numbers before or after it.

Comment: I'm terrible at RegEx too, but before coming here I give it a shot. Try here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/ Stack Overflow isn't a place for people to do your work for you, it's for getting help with the work YOU are doing.

Comment: While you can do this as a regex, it might be clearer to parse the number and check it is between 2000 and 9999, unless you want numbers like `02000` to not match.

Comment: @Pete Thanks for the link, looks like a helpful site.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Im sorry i am rather noobish, what do you mean by parse the number? Do you mean use Integer.parseInt and see if it works?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a regex you can write

```
[2-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]
```

or

```
[2-9][0-9]{3}
```

or

```
[2-9]\d{3}
```

or

```
[2-9]\p{Digit}{3}
```

This will give you all numbers between 2000 and 9999 assuming they have no leading zeros. i.e. 002000 or +2000 will not match.

What I would do is

```
int i = Integer.parseInt(text);
if (2000 <= i && i <= 9999) 
   // ok.
```

Comment: shorter version     `[2-9][0-9]{3}`

Comment: Thank you, should i use ^[2-9][0-9]{3}$ since there isn't suppose to be anything before or after the number?

Comment: If you use a matcher, that is what it will do anyway. i.e. it depends on how the regex is used.